# How to implement generic max function?

Tags: c++, templates

I know this is because the return type of the template function is same as that of the first argument (T).
How can I modify this template so that, it behaves correctly in all cases?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T, typename U>
T max(T x, U y)
{
    return x>y ? x : y;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<max(17.9,17)<<"\n";
    cout<<max(17,17.9)<<"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
17.9  
17
```

Comment: It is misbehaving, because it's doing implicit cast to either `double` or `int`. You could write specialized versions for the standard types.

Comment: @Moritz, The question is not about how to find the maximum of 2 numbers.

Comment: @cppcoder: I got that. However, if you change to template<typename T> as David suggested, you have the exact same behavior as std::max, and even if not its very very similar, so I was just curious why you wanted/needed to implement your own - isn't that what comments are for? It was an honest question, sorry if it came off the wrong way

Comment: You should be weary of `using namespace std`. There is an `std::max`, you have your own `max`, it is asking for trouble...

Comment: The question is what would your *correct* behavior be. For example, what type is the return of `max(6, 3.5)`? If you want that to be `int` then it is impossible, if you are willing to get `6.0` as result, then you just need to find the promoted type of the operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is correct. You never specified a type, so complaining that it didn't use the type you wanted it to use is not reasonable. If you want a specific type, you have to ensure both parameters *are* that type.

You could cast the first parameter to a `double`. Or you could specifically invoke
 `max<double, double>`. You could also specialize `max<int, double>` and similar combinations if you really, really wanted to.

Comment: Scwartz, Does that mean, in this case, only `template <typename T>` is useful? All other combinations needs to be specialized.

Comment: @cppcoder not necessarily. You just need to decide what you want to return for two different input types. Then you can implement that using `auto` plus trailing return type, or `std::result_of`.

Comment: I used this option : `cout<<max<double>(17,17.9)<<"\n";`

Answer (score 10):

The behaviour for *your* implementation is correct, though you may not want that output. The problem with the *return type* in your code.

You may want to use [*trailing-return type*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax) if you can use C++11:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto max(T x, U y) -> decltype(x>y ? x : y)    //C++11 only
{
    return x>y ? x : y;
}
```

which would give this output:

```
17.9
17.9
```

I hope that is the desired output.

Online demo : http://ideone.com/2Sh5Y

Answer (score 4):

with c++11 its easy, use std::common_type<> trait:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::common_type<T,U>::type max(T x, U y) /// why not const& T and const& U ?
{
    return x>y ? x : y;
}
```

common_type<> uses decltype keyword and declval<> trait which are both new since c++11

Comment: +1 Re. the comment: for primitive types you don't want to pass references, as the cost might actually be larger than copying the values. That being said, there is nothing that blocks users from passing more complex types like `std::string`

Comment: `declval` is not a *keyword*. It is function template. `decltype` is a keyword in C++11.

Comment: `declval` isn't a trait either. As I said before (6 years back), it's a function template.

Answer (score 2):

This is answer for C++03. For C++11 - use auto/decltype (see other answers).

You have to create another template: `template CommonNumericType<T1,T2>`:

```
template <typename L, typename R>
typename CommonNumericType<T1,T2>::Type max(L x, R y)
{
    return x>y ? x : y;
}
```

And specialize this CommonNumericType for every possible pair of numeric types:

```
template <typename L, typename R>
struct CommonNumericType;
template <typename T>
struct CommonNumericType<T,T> {
   typedef T Type;
};
template <typename L>
struct CommonNumericType<L,long double> {
   typedef long double Type;
};
template <typename R>
struct CommonNumericType<long double,R> {
   typedef long double Type;
};
// ...
template <>
struct CommonNumericType<int,short> {
   typedef int Type;
};
// and many others stuff
```

I can think of making some numeric types hierarchy - float types before int types - and so on. Because `<number of numeric types>^2` is quite big number:

```
template <typename T>
struct NumericTypeOrder;
template <>
struct NumericTypeOrder<long double> { enum { VALUE = 1 }; };
template <>
struct NumericTypeOrder<double> { enum { VALUE = 2 }; };
template <>
struct NumericTypeOrder<float> { enum { VALUE = 3 }; };
template <>
struct NumericTypeOrder<unsigned long long> { enum { VALUE = 4 }; };
// etc for all numeric types - where signed char is last one...

template <typename L, typename R, bool L_bigger_than_R>
struct CommonNumericTypeImpl;
template <typename L, typename R>
struct CommonNumericTypeImpl<L,R,true> {
  typedef L type;
};
template <typename L, typename R>
struct CommonNumericTypeImpl<L,R,false> {
  typedef R type;
};
template <typename L, typename R>
struct CommonNumericType 
: CommonNumericTypeImpl<L,R,NumericTypeOrder<L>::value >= NumericTypeOrder<R>::value > {
};
```

Or just use macro:

```
#define max(l,r) ((l) >= (r) ? (l) : (r))
```

Much simpler, isn't it?

Comment: +1 for the C++03 effort. Regarding the macro, it has all the problems of macros, and in particular the fact that it evaluates *one* of the arguments twice. Consider `max( f(), g() )`: that will evaluate `f`, then `g` and then the one that produced the maximum again. Besides the cost of the operation, the fact that the functions are multiply evaluated will break if they have side effects.

Comment: My gut feeling says that typelist can help implementing `CommonNumericType` more elegantly.

Comment: @David - you are right about macro. But with macro you can assign value to bigger variable: `max(a,b) = 7` where a,b are variables. I remember some article about how to achieve `max(...)` assignable with templates - but I cannot find it now.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: I know the article, it was by Alexandrescu, if that helps narrow the search. I believe it was published in DrDobbs. At any rate it was a horrible beast of 174 lines of code... I think this is it: http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-min-and-max-redivivus/184403774

Comment: @Navaz - I believe I saw somewhere implementation with typelist. Anyway I provided the other solutions - simpler than my previous one - but I am not sure if it is simpler than with typelist...

Comment: @David - Yes, this is the mentioned article. I cannot find the link - thanks for sharing it. I learnt quite a lot from it.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can use type inference (with `auto`, late return types and `decltype`):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto max(T x, U y) -> decltype(x>y ? x : y)
{
  return x>y ? x : y;
}
```