# forcing a template function to treat integers as doubles, or the type with higher precision

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, casting, dynamic-cast

This question can be stupid depending how you would look at it.

Out of curiosity I wanted to implement a `get_max` function which can return the maximum of two similar or distinct types. I know std already has this but:

```
template <class T, class U>
T get_max(T lh, U rh) {
    if(lh >= rh) return lh;
    else return rh;
}
```

Somewhere in the main:

```
int a = 10;
double d = 20.01;
std::cout << "a=" << a << "\nd=" << d << "\nget_max=" <<
    get_max(a,d) << std::endl;
```

The result surprised me:

```
a=10
d=20.01
get_max=20
```

I was expecting to have `get_max` to output 20.01, but it outputed an int. I can understand because the first argument is `int` then the `T` in the function returns `T` which in this case is obviously `int` so the function returns the bigger of the two arguments, but casts it to the type of the first argument.

Is there a way to somehow make the code smart to return the `double` or the type with higher precision?

I know for a fact that passing the `double` as the first argument would be a naive way of fixing the problem!

Comment: Your question is not stupid. You can use std:: conditional for the return type to select between two return types based on a Boolean expression, which could be a comparison of the sizes of the two types. You'd probably want something more complicated though to avoid truncation.

Comment: I would never could find that duplicate by that title, but it is the first time I see a duplicate question is actually can be a legit duplicate :D

Comment: The tree with eyes! thanks.

Comment: @NirFriedman Thanks. I will look it up.

Comment: @SaeidYazdani Tried to fix the title; found it because I knew the answer and could search for that.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12159396/2249683